# Vmware Workstation downloads as a txt file?

Tags: installation, vmware-workstation

I just went to the vmware website because I want to try workstation over virtualbox. I [signed up for a workstation trial and clicked download on the 64bit linux version](https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/p/activate.php?p=vmware-workstation8&lp=1).  What downloaded is a 320 megabyte txt file `VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.txt`

What gives? Is anyone familiar with this pattern of delivering software? How do I run it?

Here is the beginning of that file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# VMware Installer Launcher
#
# This is the executable stub to check if the VMware Installer Service
# is installed and if so, launch it.  If it is not installed, the
# attached payload is extracted, the VMIS is installed, and the VMIS
# is launched to install the bundle as normal.

# Architecture this bundle was built for (x86 or x64)
ARCH=x64

if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then
   # $- expands to the current options so things like -x get passed through
   if [ ! -z "$-" ]; then
      opts="-$-"
   fi

   # dash flips out of $opts is quoted, so don't.
   exec /usr/bin/env bash $opts "$0" "$@"
   echo "Unable to restart with bash shell"
   exit 1
fi

set -e

ETCDIR=/etc/vmware-installer
OLDETCDIR="/etc/vmware"

### Offsets ###
# These are offsets that are later used relative to EOF.
FOOTER_SIZE=52

# This won't work with non-GNU stat.
FILE_SIZE=`stat --format "%s" "$0"`
offset=$(($FILE_SIZE - 4))

MAGIC_OFFSET=$offset
offset=$(($offset - 4))

CHECKSUM_OFFSET=$offset
offset=$(($offset - 4))

VERSION_OFFSET=$offset
offset=$(($offset - 4))

PREPAYLOAD_OFFSET=$offset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have yourself a shell script there. While technically text (not a binary file), these generally end in much more readily identifiable extensions, such as '.sh'.

This is meant to be run in, and interpreted by, a shell, such as [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29).

Edit:

This appears to be an issue with Chrome/Chromium (I replicated the issue with chromium 17.somethingorother), as FF download this properly (as indicated by the download link), as a '.bundle':

VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle

The .bundle appears to be a way of tying a text-based installer with a binary data set so that you just have the one file.

For what it's worth, there's no need to even change the extension at all, the shell interpreter knows what to do (and the interpreter is invoked with the ['shebang'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the start of the file: '#!/bin/bash').

Comment: Edited the link into my answer

Comment: `sudo chmod u+x VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.txt; mv VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.sh; sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.sh` Seems to have done the trick. But who on earth distributes files like this?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer See my edit above.